# MVC4 Multiple Databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I'm new to MVC4 framework & been working on an Licensing application that must use different databases for different products (each database contains handful tables for one product - all generated by proprietary licensing tool). My application shall be able to support CRUD functions on various products, thus requiring more than one `DbContext` objects in relation to different model for each product.

As far as I know, each such `DbContext` object requires a connection string in the `Web.config` file. I'm struggling to list (`Index.cshtml`) existing licences for various products, using `DropDownList` control, as for each product I'd need to connect to a different database whenever the user choose a different product from the `DropDownList` control.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand your question, the core issue is you are struggling to connect to a different db, whenever user selects a different product from a DropDownList. As you said, yes DbContext object requires a connection string in the Web.config file. You can specify [multiple connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530284/multiple-sql-server-connection-strings-in-app-config-file) in a config.
Also you can definitely pass different connection strings to [DBContext constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=VS.103%29.aspx). Typically your DAL/Data Access Layer or Repository layer would pull appropriate connection string from the Web.Config/App.config and pass it to the DBContext constructor. See a similar approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739666/how-create-multiple-db-context-intances-by-conntecting-strings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570180/multiple-string-connections-in-ef-dbcontext).

**UPDATE :**

You cannot share the same DbContext with multiple databases. You need [multiple DbContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190310/multiple-dbcontext-multiple-database-setinitializer) for each of your DB.

*Additional* 
There are few of doing this, but if you use Repostory and Unit Of Work pattern, you can use an approach like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406025525/http://www.storminajar.net/2011/12/13/supporting-multiple-databases-using-the-unit-of-work-and-repository-patterns)

Each DbContext you going to have, you can associate with set of entities within that database in context. Something like below

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext ()
        : base("connectionStringA")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Accounts { get; set; }
}


public class LicenceContext : DbContext
{
    public LicenceContext ()
        : base("connectionStringB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Licence> Licenses{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean that `DbContext` object is not tied to any particular model class? Can I have more than one model classes under a `DbContext` (sorry, but I am really new to this!)? From the examples it seems that both the databases have same table schema, which is not the case with my databases, would passing different connection strings in ctor work, given that I have different classes in my Model?

Comment: @Kunal I have updated the answer for your comments/questions.

Comment: Thanks Spock! I know...very delayed response. But your various options have come to work for me. I now have two connection strings and only one DBContext. After revisiting your answers a few times, I refactored my model and DB that they reflect the same fields. Upon user interaction I simply reinitialise the DBContext with the new connection string. And everything works like a charm! Thanks for your help! :-)