# Storing personal data across countries MVC c#

Tags: azure

I have a system i am developing for a company that will in the future open branches for our customers to sign up for in multiple countries (Singapore / UK / USA)  Each of these different countries have rules about which information can be stored outside their region (e.g. EU Safe Harbour)

What is the development method to ensure that specific information is read / stored in specific databases while maintaining wherever possible a central report of data across the company?  Do i need to have multiple database connections and use only a specific one when i am dealing with multiple locations?  Do i need to store some data separately?  what is a good way to deal with this kind of info?

The system i am building is a booking engine for member "sessions"

Comment: Your question is way too broad for a simple answer - your application will need a proper architecture to work correctly (and most of that architecture won't have anything to do with MVC, which is only the UI layer). Read about service architectures as a starter.

Comment: There's no right answer for this. Data sovereignty is more a legal issue than  a technical one, but you'll need to work out a proper approach that keeps data within a region (and this goes beyond just a database; it also involves any additional services/vm's/etc that handle, and possibly persist, data. It's off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use multiple connection strings, i.e. one for each region, and then a master one. Then your app would connect to a region specific database using the connection string based on what region it's running in. See this answer for implementation: [MVC4 Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349573/mvc4-multiple-databases)

This is assuming that you're storing information only in the database. If you have additional areas of storage (i.e. blob storage), you're going to need to handle that as well.

Comment: Would this be easy to implement on a user by user basis? i.e. if i was connecting to a specific user could i retrieve that from a specific database that the user would be in ?

Comment: That question is too broad, it could go either way. You could use the region database, you could use the master database or you could use both and on your master database you could have a lookup table of which would show which region databases the user is in. Depends on your app.